# What's this number called and what are its properties?

Tags: real-numbers

What is the following number called and what are its known properties?
$$.12233344445555566666677777778888888899999999910101010101010101010...$$
(I think you get the pattern.)

P.S.Also, see what I did with the integer part there? :)

Comment: I honestly don't think it has a name...

Comment: It's just one of the infinitely many irrational numbers.

Comment: @mfl so is $\phi$, but it's still got a name :)

Comment: Yes, but $\phi,\pi,e, \cdots$ have a lot of importance in mathematics. I don't think so of the number you have written.

Comment: OK, so let's give it a name: "user132181's number".

Comment: @RobertIsrael my life is complete now! :)

Comment: It is not direct, but if you replace each repeated digit by $0001$ of appropriate length, you have http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function Ramanujan's $f(1/10,1).$ I suspect this is included in hte proofs of transcendency by Wadim Zudilin's adviser, Nesterenko http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=83363  I imagine standard manipulations with power series, such as are often asked about on MSE, should take this to your number. My guess is transcendental. Here we go, identity for $f(q,q^3)$ is better.

Comment: See [Champernowne constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant), [Copeland-Erdos constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copeland-Erdos_constant), and [Liouville number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number).

Comment: @Lucian I do know about these as well, and they too look an awful lot similiar to the number above, but still... who knows? Maybe this number has some magical super-properties that none of the other popular numbers has.

Comment: I read it as $10$ repeating so, I thought, it's a rational. But, now, I see it...

Comment: As an integer sequence it has an [entry in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C2%2C3%2C3%2C3%2C4%2C4%2C4%2C4%2C5%2C5%2C5%2C5%2C5%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7&sort=&language=english&go=Search).

Answer (score -3):

It shares thematic similarity w/ the "look and say sequence" described by John Horton Conway in the mid 1980s. That's a pyramid where every row beneath the first one 'describes' the previous row (e.g. The second row '1 1' describes the first row '1' when spoken as "one one").

Comment: Yes, I know about that sequence and it does feel a bit similar to the number above, but unfortunately this doesn't answer my question :(